# How to open Window File Explorer from web browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want open folder in Window File Explorer from any web browser by click but open in web browser windows. I want to open folder in window file explorer.

[Edit] I have not found any resolution. Please remove duplicate flag.

Comment: I'm also looking for it

Comment: which platform.?

Comment: Also - Linking to local resources is disabled in all modern browsers due to security restrictions.

Comment: Not possible. JavaScript doesn't have access to the OS. Unless you *absolutely, positively* know a local folder that exists, you can't access it. If you do, you can use the `file://` protocol like `file://c:/Windows` but this won't necessarily open Windows File Explorer, nor necessarily work on all browsers. It won't even work on Linux or Mac.

Comment: The closest thing you can do is to use an `<input type="file" />` control to open the file picker dialog, but this won't let you choose a specific folder to open.

Comment: I want to open my sharepoint folder document path in window file explorer.

Comment: @Craicerjack I have try all this but not working. all methods open my folder on browser not in window file explorer.

Comment: yes because - Linking to local resources is disabled in all modern browsers due to security restrictions.

Comment: you can create first .cmd file and add command to open file explorer and give it for download to user. follow this links https://khailiangtech.wordpress.com/2011/06/07/how-to-create-a-cmd-command-file/ , https://www.watchingthenet.com/open-display-folders-in-windows-explorer-from-the-command-prompt.html

Comment: you also need to add mime in web.config  <staticContent> <mimeMap fileExtension=".bat" mimeType="application/bat" /> </staticContent>