# Open folder in Windows Explorer using Native File System API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, file-access, native-file-system-api-js

Note: There are already some questions on how to open Folder on User device using Javascript. however, these questions were asked, before the [Native File System API](https://web.dev/native-file-system/).

1. [How to open Window File Explorer from web browser using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58374754/how-to-open-window-file-explorer-from-web-browser-using-javascript)
2. [Open local folder from link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246292/open-local-folder-from-link)
3. [Open a folder in finder/explorer from a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485355/open-a-folder-in-finder-explorer-from-a-webpage)

My question is very specific, is there a way to open a folder in default file explore (ie Windows Explorer in Windows and Finder in Mac) using the new "Native File System API".

Answer (score 1):

This is how I am opening a directory and store the handlers in an array

```js
 try {
        const directoryHandle = await window.showDirectoryPicker()
        const files = []

        for await (let [name, handle] of directoryHandle) {
          const file = await handle.getFile()

         // if you want to access the content of the file 
         const content = await file.text()
         
         files.push({
            name,
            handle,
            file,
            content,
          })
        }
        console.log('', files)
```

More to read https://wicg.github.io/file-system-access/#filesystemdirectoryhandle

Comment: How would I do them all at parralel?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I wanted to open and read all files in parallel, rather than wait to read the file close it and then read next. In my code, I only read the first 5000bits of the file so it is a reasonable thing to do :) I managed to do it with files being an array of promises of `handle.getFile().then(...)`